# Correct way to compile Settings.apk in android

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I have Mini Cyanogenmod sources on my laptop.
So I did `make Settings` to compile Settings.apk from source. (I don't wanna compile the whole ROM)

And compilation finished nicely and I got Settings.apk compiled.

So I pushed Settings.apk to `/system/app` by the following commands :

```
adb root
adb push Settings.apk /system/app
```

The file successfully copies. But now the Settings app is itself removed from the app drawer. I tried setting the permissions of apk but it didn't work either. And when I push the original apk to /system/app the Settings app reappears in the app drawer.

What could be the problem of my compiled apk is not working.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that push Settings.apk to **/system/app**. You should push Settings.apk to "**/system/priv-app/Settings/**" by the following command:

`adb push Settings.apk /system/priv-app/Settings/`

Steps are described as follows：

1. root and romount the filesystem.
2. push Settings.apk to the right directory.
3. reboot.

The corresponding commands are:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push Settings.apk /system/priv-app/Settings/
adb reboot
```

Comment: your explication is unclear, there's a lot of typos and it gets messy. To me the Tip you're giving doesn't make sens in common English. Try to rework your answer a bit.